# Angular 5 Material date picker does not support "DD/MM/YYYY" Format using input

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, angular5

My problem is the date picker does not support "DD/MM/YYYY" Format using input, only support by using calendar. and i need that the date picker should allow user enter date '25/11/2016' by using text input.

```
providers: [
{provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MyDateAdapter},
{provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: CUSTOM_DATE_FORMAT }, 
{provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'fr-FR'},],
```

and the custom date format

```
 export const CUSTOM_DATE_FORMAT = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'DD/DD/YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    /* monthYearLabel: 'MMMM YYYY', */
    dateA11yLabel: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    /* monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY', */
  },
};
```

the Date adapter

```
import { NativeDateAdapter } from "@angular/material";

export class MyDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
    format(date: Date, displayFormat: Object): string {
        if (displayFormat == "input") {
            let day = date.getDate();
            let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
            let year = date.getFullYear();
            return this._to2digit(day) + '/' + this._to2digit(month) + '/' + year;
        } else {
            return date.toDateString();
        }
    }

    private _to2digit(n: number) {
        return ('00' + n).slice(-2);
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse user manual input you need to override the following method in your custom NativeDateAdapter

parse(value: any): Date | null

You can do something like that (or better use date libs like moment.js for parsing):

```
  export class CustomDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
    parse(value: any): Date | null {
      if (!value) { return null; }
      return this.toDate(value);
    }

    private toDate(dateStr) {
      const [day, month, year] = dateStr.split(/[-\/.]/);
      return new Date(year, month - 1, day);
    }
    ......................
  }
```

Alternatively, you can use MomentDateAdapter

https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-parse-and-display-formats

And here is an example https://stackblitz.com/angular/qdbqggxyelv?file=app%2Fdatepicker-formats-example.ts

Answer (score 2):

Add in @Ngmodule

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
    parse: {
        dateInput: 'MM.DD.YYYY'
    },
    display: {
        dateInput: 'MM.DD.YYYY',
        monthYearLabel: 'MM YYYY',
        dateA11yLabel: 'MM.DD.YYYY',
        monthYearA11yLabel: 'MM YYYY'
    }
};

  providers: [{ provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS }, { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'fr-FR' }]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, simply and elegant.

Answer (score 1):

try this using locale

```
import { DateAdapter } from '@angular/material';

constructor(private dateAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>) {
    this.dateAdapter.setLocale('your locale');
}
```